# Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment when running map

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, android-fragments

I have some problemes when executing a simple map in android studio,

here is my map activity :

```
package com.dev.boblinux.cador.activities;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.dev.boblinux.cador.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class CHomeMapCtrl extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chome_map_ctrl);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
    //mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(48.856614, 2.3522219000000177)));
    }
}
```

here is my AndroidManifest
`

```
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->

<!-- this permission is required to run WebView -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<!-- this permission is required to send sms -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<!-- this permission is required to receive sms -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<!-- this permission is required to read sms -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="com.dev.boblinux.cador.activities.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.dev.boblinux.cador.activities.CHomeMapCtrl"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_chome_map_ctrl" />

    <!-- this line let sms receiver running in background-->

    <receiver android:name="com.dev.boblinux.cador.activities.SmsReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

and here is my map ressource :

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.CHomeMapCtrl" />
```

Last but not least, this is my error code :

```
02-07 21:36:59.773 2497-2497/com.dev.boblinux.cador E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.dev.boblinux.cador, PID: 2497
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dev.boblinux.cador/com.dev.boblinux.cador.activities.CHomeMapCtrl}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
at com.dev.boblinux.cador.activities.CHomeMapCtrl.onCreate(CHomeMapCtrl.java:23)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
at com.dev.boblinux.cador.activities.CHomeMapCtrl.onCreate(CHomeMapCtrl.java:23) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.io.File.mkdir()' on a null object reference
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.ad.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.h.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.ao.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.bd.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.ev.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.z.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.y.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1226)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1328)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2284)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutIn
```

The problemes seems to come at my `AndroidManifest`, but i don't know where, my `android:name` seems to be ok, so what the problem?

Thanks for helping me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tryed on my tablet and its works ..., so i don't know if i make this post resolved, but the problem is due to Emulator

Answer (score 1):

This is the bottomline of your error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.io.File.mkdir()' on a null object reference
```

You need to insert an SD card. See [issues tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9021&q=NullPointerException&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal).

Comment: I'm using the emulator, so SD card is included on emulator ? I'll try tonight on real device and i'll see

Comment: You can put an SD card in an emulator by going to the Advanced Settings of the AVD Manager while creating the emulator then increase the size there.

Comment: Thanks for trying helping me !                                                                      I had 100 mb on my sd card, and i put 800 mb, but i have the same problem, i don't understand =/

Comment: I tryed on my tablet and its works ..., so i don't know if i make this post resolved, but the problem is due to Emulator